# Terraform - inconsistent conditional result types, from same map

Tags: terraform

I have a map of values, and I'm basically trying to replace a number of different values while in a giant loop.

I've gotten so far, and feel like I've almost got this working but stumbling at what maybe the final step.

```
 Error: Inconsistent conditional result types
│ 
│   on main.tf line 25, in locals:
│   25:       source_ranges = distinct(flatten([for source in [for source in v.source_ranges_names : source == "#Env" ? replace(source, "#Env", env) : (length(regexall("#Env_customer_cidr", source)) > 0 && env == "prod" ? local.defined_ranges["prod_customer_cidr"] : (length(regexall("#Env_customer_cidr", source)) > 0 && env == "test" ? local.defined_ranges["test_customer_cidr"] : local.defined_ranges[source] ))]: local.defined_ranges[source] ]))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.defined_ranges is object with 18 attributes
│     │ local.defined_ranges["prod_customer_cidr"] is tuple with 1 element
│     │ local.defined_ranges["test_customer_cidr"] is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
│ expressions are string and list of string, respectively.
```

I don't understand the cause of the error, as I'm referring back to the same object each time and the values in the object are all defined the same way:

```
   "defined_ranges": {
        "random_cidr": [
            "192.168.1.0/24"
        ],
        "prod_customer_cidr": [
            "192.168.2.0/24"
        ],
        "test_customer_cidr": [
            "192.168.3.0/24"
        ],
    }
```

In the example error above, source would have a value such as 'random_cidr'.

I realise this can likely be refactored into something far easier to read/understand but I'm still getting my head around what the terraform is doing.

Comment: What `v.source_ranges_names` is supposed to be?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you have `local.defined_ranges is object with 18 attributes`? What are these 18 attributes? Your question shows only 3.

Comment: v.source_range_names is a list of the names of the ranges we want to swap, for their IP counterparts.

As for defined ranges, there's more other named IP ranges which I may need to swap into the statement, but I haven't included them all as I'd need to change the names and IP addresses anyway.

Comment: `v.source_range_names` is not a valid TF code. Is it `var.source_range_names`? Sadly your question is not clear, without the context with all variables and locals.